# Why am I getting redeclared errors when trying to build any Go program?

Tags: go

I want to learn Go. I installed Go 1.13.5 on 64-bit Windows 10. I started out trying to build the following hello world program:

```golang
package hello

import ("fmt")

func main() {
    fmt.Printf("Hello world!")

}
```

However, when I try to build it or any other Go program, I get errors

```
c:\go\src\runtime\stubs_x86.go:10:6: stackcheck redeclared in this block
        previous declaration at c:\go\src\runtime\stubs_amd64x.go:10:6
c:\go\src\runtime\unaligned1.go:11:6: readUnaligned32 redeclared in this block
        previous declaration at c:\go\src\runtime\alg.go:321:40
c:\go\src\runtime\unaligned1.go:15:6: readUnaligned64 redeclared in this block
        previous declaration at c:\go\src\runtime\alg.go:329:40
```

Does anyone know what is going wrong?

Comment: how do you install go? did you just clone it from the go github repo?

Comment: Did you upgrade from another version?

Comment: @Adrian, yep, apparently the Windows for Go does not completely remove ``C:\Go `` like it should. I had to manually delete the directory after running the uninstaller.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems a common issue of Go v1.13. You can try to do a clean uninstall and reinstall. See [this post](https://www.reddit.com/r/golang/comments/d2srx1/newbie_qissues_with_113/).

Comment: @Adrian, yep, apparently the Windows for Go does not completely remove ``C:\Go `` like it should. I had to manually delete the directory after running the uninstaller. Thanks!